# Extract polygons which contain an attribute of a list

Tags: fme-form

I have a problem regarding a shapefile and a list. To make it simple, I try to depict the problem using an image:

I have a list of elements:
`List_Elements={"Apple", Carrot", "Pineapple", "Tomato", "Asparagus"}`

Then I have a shapefile containing polygons and in the attribute table I have a string-typed field called `MEO`.

`MEO` can contain any of the elements of the `List_Elements` or something else like "Orange".
Using FME I now want to extract all polygons for which have a `MEO` who is inside my list `List_Elements`.

I tried using a `Tester` from FME but I cannot loop through the list of attributes for this. Is there any other transformer or method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to explode the list to features using a ListExploder, connect these to the supplier port of a FeatureMerger, connect the polygons to the requestor port and configure the FeatureMerger to match MEO on the list attribute.

Output merged is polygon with attribute MEO which is in the list.

As an alternative you can merge the list to each polygon using a FeatureMerger set to 1=1 and then use a ListSearcher to find if the value of the MEO attribute is in the list. But I doubt this performs better.

Comment: I used the trick using the FeatureMerger. Works like a charm. Thanks!